# Using BroadcastReceiver in stopped application in Android 3.1+

Tags: android

Is there a way to receive broadcasts(like sms notification) in stopped application?
Actually it works simply in lower than Android 3.1.

EDIT 1:
Thanks to @Squonk for comment.
So my questions is, is it REALLY impossible? you can check PlanB app in market which does this  things.

EDIT 2:
this is my broadcast receiver. The onReceive function is never called(when application is stopped).

```
public class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.e("kpav", "kpav");
        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(32);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));

        arg0.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android v3.1 onwards, any app which has been manually started at least once by the user, will receive broadcasts that it has registered in the manifest even after a reboot.

BUT...the user must have manually started that app - it's not possible for an app to be installed and have it automatically receive broadcasts otherwise.

Also, if the user manually uses 'Force Stop' from the Settings on a device, it will no longer receive broadcasts until the user manually starts the app again.

So basically, in answer to your question...

> Is there a way to receive broadcasts(like sms notification) in stopped application?

...the answer is no except under the circumstances I describe above.

Comment: check PlanB app in the market, how it works if it is not possible?

Comment: I think we had this conversation yesterday. PLAN B exploited a security hole which was closed with v3.1 onwards as it was open to potential abuse by malware.

Answer (score 1):

You can inlcude **Stopped Packages** to receive broadcasts by simply adding the following flag to the broadcasting intent.

```
intent.addFlags(32);
```

Where as `32` refers to [`Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES) which is available from **API level 12**.

Comment: can you help me more specifically how to do this.

Comment: just add/set a flag with value **32** (for example `intent.addFlags(32);`) to your broadcasting intent and it will be listened by all those packages too which are marked as *Stopped*

Comment: yes, the time when you broadcast your intent (with-in code) then add that flag

Comment: please check my edit. the probelm is the onReceive function is never called

Comment: ahaan, so you are trying to get sms received broadcast. Since this broadcast is generated by system, so you cant add flag value 32 in it's intent. However, what you can do is to pop-up an activity (lets say *License Agreement*) to activate your package prior to start receiving broadcasts

Comment: Where I can pop-up that Activity? there is really no place

Comment: just add an activity to your application so that user can select your app's icon available in launcher

Comment: I want to run BroadcastReceiver without user interaction

Comment: then its simply not possible (at the moment)